# System volume locked on Mac mini when using HDMI audio

Tags: mac-mini, hdmi, television

I just connected my Mac mini (Late 2012) to my TV using HDMI.

Now, all works good, except that I cannot set system volume on the HDMI link. That is, if I switch from built-in speaker to HDMI audio, system volume is locked and I cannot adjust it.

Under Windows (Boot Camp), by contrast, I can adjust system volume, so it's not hardware-related issue.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that since you use a digital link (the same behaviour is exhibited when you use the optic interface) the modulation must a high as possible to get the best sound quality possible.

This is because when lowering the modulation you reduce the amount of significant bits that "describes" the sound : the resolution and dynamic range of the source signal is lowered.

So, even if it is theoretically possible, that's not a good advice from an audiophile point of view. I guess that's why Apple decided to lock the volume control when using those links.

Regarding the workaround, you may try to install soundflower : http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090111110741237

Comment: I'm not an audiophile. Just want to adjust volume via mac remote control.. :) Thanks for your advice.

Comment: By the way, Sunflower refuses to start on El Capitan..